# Scraping links that I don't want to but I don't know how to exclude

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Let's say I have this structure

```
<div data-next="link0">
   <a href="link1"/>
   <a href="link2"/>
   <a href="link3"/>
   <a href="link4"/>
</div>
```

and with my rule object I want to access only link0, without accessing link1, link2, link3, link4.

How can I do that?

I tried

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@data-next]/@data-next')), callback='parse_item'),
```

but it won't work, because I need a reference to an element, not the link directly. But if I remove @data-next, link1, link2, link3, link4 will be scraped too.

So, is there any way to scrape just link0 using the Rule object in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@data-next]', tags='div', attrs='data-next'), callback='parse_item'),
```

`LinkExtractor` looks for `<a>` tags and `@href` attr by default. In this case, you have to specify which tags and attributes it should include in the search. More on that from [Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml):

> **Parameters:**
>
> (...)
>
> - **tags** (str or list) – a tag or a list of tags to consider when extracting links. Defaults to `('a', 'area')`.
> - **attrs** (list) – an attribute or list of attributes which should be considered when looking for links to extract (only for those tags specified in the tags parameter). Defaults to `('href',)`

Comment: This has solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the below `xpath`

```
//div[@data-next="link0]
```

Comment: What if I don't know for sure the content of data-next? My data-next attribute for the divs I want to scrape look like this: /ro/locuri-de-munca/relevant/{AN-INTEGER-WHICH-CHANGES}?keyword=programator&location=bucuresti&scroll=true - the link is the same, only {AN-INTEGER-WHICH-CHANGES} changes